# JSON deserialization parsing C#

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, json, dictionary

I want to parse the following json to dictionary or a class object, i am using JSON.net, but i don't understand how to create dictionary structure or even a class structure to parse it into object. I have seen json array parsing using JObject but i don't get how to implement that for this type of json structure.

```
 {
  "room": 1,
  "meta": {},
  "devices": [
    {
      "asset": {
        "id": "asset_big_lamp_1"
      },
      "device_name": "Lamp_1",
      "device_type": "light",
      "power_usage": "low",
      "ui_coordinates": {
        "x": "3.5",
        "y": "-2.6",
        "z": "-3.6"
      },
      "transducers": {
        "relay": "ARE00",
        "dimmer": "null"
      }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! What have you done so far? What has/hasn't worked?

Comment: Create your class according to this JSon. After it parse it `var res = (YourClass)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(s, typeof(YourClass));`

Comment: Use System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer `Dictionary<string, object> JSONDict = (Dictionary<string, object>)(new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()).DeserializeObject(JSON);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON is not a valid JSON. It should be :

```
{
   "room": 1,
   "meta": {

   },
   "devices": [
     {
       "asset": {
       "id": "asset_big_lamp_1"
     },
     "device_name": "Lamp_1",
     "device_type": "light",
     "power_usage": "low",
     "ui_coordinates": {
       "x": "3.5",
       "y": "-2.6",
       "z": "-3.6"
     },
     "transducers": {
       "relay": "ARE00",
       "dimmer": "null"
     }
    }
  ]
}
```

It is represented in C# by the following classes :

```
public class Root
{
    public int room { get; set; }
    public Meta meta { get; set; }
    public Device[] devices { get; set; }
}

public class Meta
{
}

public class Device
{
    public Asset asset { get; set; }
    public string device_name { get; set; }
    public string device_type { get; set; }
    public string power_usage { get; set; }
    public Ui_Coordinates ui_coordinates { get; set; }
    public Transducers transducers { get; set; }
}

public class Asset
{
    public string id { get; set; }
}

public class Ui_Coordinates
{
    public string x { get; set; }
    public string y { get; set; }
    public string z { get; set; }
}

public class Transducers
{
    public string relay { get; set; }
    public string dimmer { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can deserialize your JSON string using the following code :

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using C# 4.0 or newer, you can take advantage of `dynamic` types.

This is an example using a well known library for JSON serialization/deserialization ([JSON.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/)):

```
dynamic data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(yourJsonString);

// data.room contains 1
// data.devices[0].device_name contains "Lamp_1"
```

If you have never used `dynamic` typing before, don't get scared if your IntelliSense does not seem to work. This is because all the properties and values are known at runtime only.